# Circuit issues in garage

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, garage, circuit, freezer

I have a freezer in my garage and we purchased a new fridge for our garage. Everything was fine for a week but suddenly the fridge gfci outlet shuts off and  turns off the power to the whole garage!
Help? Is it possible all my outlets in my garage are on one circuit? Is that code for Oregon?
This is a new build.
I don’t know what to do.

It appears to somehow just trip the outlet and not the switch in the breaker box.

Comment: A new fridge should work on GFCIs these days.  There is a problem with pre 2008 fridges on GFCIs.  Having more than one or two outlets on a circuit is quite common.  If the fridge trips the GFCI then it should be a free replacement/repair from the company.  If the GFCI trips by itself(old age) then replacing the GFCI is needed.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing at all unusual in having all outlets in a garage on a single circuit, in Oregon or anywhere else. GFCI's are notorious for nuisance tripping, especially when used with tools and appliances with motors. You could try having the GFCI replaced with a different brand. Under some circumstances, GFCI's can be replaced with ordinary receptacles without violating any electrical codes. There's little doubt that problematic GFCI's are frequently removed by the folks who have to live with them regardless of what electrical codes say.

Comment: And their is little doubt that unprotected garage outlets kill people or the GFCI requirement would not be code… Remember that code is written in blood, and you want to be sure it isn’t yours.